# how can i check that a json file already has something inside?

Tags: python, json

I have this json file where it contains a name and a code:

```json
{
    "CDIA": [
        {
            "name": "Pablo",
            "cdia": "XB&DE@E+TY"
        },
        {
            "name": "Elena",
            "cdia": "KB?D+@EHTY"
        },
        {
            "name": "Pedro",
            "cdia": "AB?DE@E+TY"
        },
        {
            "name": "Miguel",
            "cdia": "AB?DE@E+TY"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, i need to make a function that checks the user input if its already on the json file or not, so i tried this:

```py
name = str(input('[?] Enter your name: '))

def Check(x):
    cdia = open('CDIA.json', 'r')
    data = json.load(cdia)
    for i in data['CDIA']:
        if x == i['name']: return True
        else: return False

if val.Check(name) == False:
    print('[!] The name is already registered.')
else:
    print("[!] The name isnt registered yet.")
```

no matter what name i enter, it keeps saying its already registered.

Comment: Why do you print "already registered" when the returned value is _False_?

Comment: It's because of your `else` clause.  Your loop will only run ONCE, because you always return.  You can't return False until you have checked every item.  Remove the `else:` line and add `return False` after the loop ends.

Comment: Also, you should read the file ONCE, not during every check.  And do not do `if xxx == False:`, the whole point of booleans is that you don't use ==.  Do `if not val.Check(name):`.  And finally, `input` always returns a string.  You do not need to call `str` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining all of my suggestions:

```
cdia = open('CDIA.json', 'r')
data = json.load(cdia)

def Check(x):
    for i in data['CDIA']:
        if x == i['name']:
            return True
    return False

name = input('[?] Enter your name: ')
if Check(name):
    print('[!] The name is already registered.')
else:
    print("[!] The name isnt registered yet.")
```